# When I open a NSManagedDocument (core data) file, it always seems empty

Tags: ios, core-data

There is something I dont understand in core data.
I have created a NSManagedDocument, made a change, and saved it.
Then I created another one and opened the file I saved.
From what I understand the NSManagedDocument should have the change I mad, but it doesn't.

here is the code I wrote:

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data Base"];
// url is now "<Documents Directory>/Default Photo Database"
self.dataBase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if (self.dataBase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    [self.dataBase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    }];
} 
Position *pos = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Position" inManagedObjectContext:self.dataBase.managedObjectContext];
pos.name = @"positon 1";


[self.dataBase saveToURL:self.dataBase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success){

}];

self.dataBase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if (self.dataBase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    [self.dataBase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    }];
} 
pos = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Position" inManagedObjectContext:self.dataBase.managedObjectContext];
pos.name = @"position 2";
```

as far as i understand I should have 2 objects for entity "Position" by now, but I only have the last one, why is that?

what am I missing here?

Comment: Please post some code where you create your managed object and how you use the NSManagedDocument. Also it would be good if you could get hold of a call-stack or any other useful information regarding the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but as soon as I moved my code to the AppDelegate it was solved...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but figured I would answer it anyway...
Opening the database is an asynchronous call.  You need to move the code where you are inserting stuff into the database into the success block of the completion handler or this won't work.  The way that you have it written you are trying to insert the position before the database has actually been opened.

```
if (self.dataBase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    [self.dataBase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        Position *pos = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Position" inManagedObjectContext:self.dataBase.managedObjectContext];
        pos.name = @"positon 1";
    }];
}
```